# Indexing rectangles in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am storing in a table a set of axis-aligned rectangles located somewhere in 2D space. Each rectangle is defined by a tuple `(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)`, representing to opposite corners of the rectangle. Each coordinate is an integer.

Typical query I make is to select all rectangles that intersect with a similar rectangular view `(Vx1, Vy1, Vx2, Vy2)`. In example:

```
SELECT * FROM Rectangles WHERE X2>=Vx1 AND Y2>=Vy1 AND X1<=Vx2 AND Y1<=Vy2
```

My question is, what indexing structure would you recommend for this kind of queries in order to reduce query time? Or maybe representing the rectangle in a different way would be beneficial for that kind of queries?

The rectangles are often fetched and seldom updated.

---

Currently I have just a straightforward single index on `X1-Y1-X2-Y2`. However, when running the above query with `EXPLAIN` I get

- type: ALL (full table scan)
- key: NULL (no index is being used)

Comment: Have a look at Spatial indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: I am looking at it, but seems much more complicated than I expected. It seems to work on some generic geometry objects, rather than a simple tuple of integer numbers. Most importantly, it seems to be working on floats (am I mistaken?), which introduces a degree of inaccuracy, which is not needed and may be harmful.

Comment: You are right in every point. It works with any shape, but uses `Minimum Bounding Rectangles`, i.e. really works with rectangles only. But, it has spatial indexes, which may speed up the queries a lot. It depends, and you'd better measure actual performance with your queries. I don't think you can do efficient search that you need with standard indexes.